# How can I establish the connection between the sensor and Arduino to C# with minimal delay?

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino-uno

This code is a C# Windows Form intended to receive sensor data from Form One and use it to play a game. It receives the data through two static variables, and the ball moves accordingly. The game is functioning correctly; however, when we connect the Arduino and the sensor with a long USB cable, the initial data transmission experiences a noticeable delay. I would like to inquire whether this delay is solely a hardware issue or if there might be a problem in my code that can be resolved.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private int ballX = 50;
        private int ballY = 50;
        private int ballSpeedX = 2;
        private int ballSpeedY = 2;
        private DateTime basketEntryTime = DateTime.MinValue;
        private int basketR;
        private string root = "C:/Users/Lenovo/source/repos/Final3/Images/";
        private int ChosenSpeed = 2;
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Interval = 50;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Update);
            timer.Start();

        private double CalculateDistanceToBasket()
        {
            double basketCenterX = ClientSize.Width / 2;
            double basketCenterY = ClientSize.Height / 2;

            double ballCenterX = ballX + 50;
            double ballCenterY = ballY + 50;

            double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(basketCenterX - ballCenterX, 2) + Math.Pow(basketCenterY - ballCenterY, 2));

            return distance;
        }

        private Random random = new Random();

        private void StartNewGame()
        {
            double minDistanceToBasket = 300;

            do
            {
                int minX = 100;
                int maxX = ClientSize.Width - 100;
                int minY = 100;
                int maxY = ClientSize.Height - 100;

                ballX = random.Next(minX, maxX);
                ballY = random.Next(minY, maxY);

            } while (CalculateDistanceToBasket() < minDistanceToBasket || OutRange(ballX, ballY));

            label1.Text = string.Empty;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private bool OutRange(int x, int y)
        {
            int minXRange = 100;
            int maxXRange = ClientSize.Width - 300;
            int minYRange = 100;
            int maxYRange = ClientSize.Height - 300;

            return x < minXRange || x > maxXRange || y < minYRange || y > maxYRange;
        }

        private async void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int eaxlasInt = (int)Math.Round(eaxlas);
            int eaylasInt = (int)Math.Round(eaylas);

            ballSpeedX = eaxlasInt;
            ballSpeedY = eaylasInt;

            ballX = ballX + (ChosenSpeed * (-ballSpeedY) / 10);
            ballY = ballY + (ChosenSpeed * (-ballSpeedX) / 10);

            if (ballX < 0) ballX = 0;

            if (ballX + 100 > ClientSize.Width) ballX = ClientSize.Width - 100;

            if (ballY < 0) ballY = 0;

            if (ballY + 100 > ClientSize.Height) ballY = ClientSize.Height - 100;

            if (CalculateDistanceToBasket() < basketR)
            {
                if (basketEntryTime == DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    basketEntryTime = DateTime.Now;
                }

                TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - basketEntryTime;

                if (elapsedTime.TotalSeconds < 5)
                {
                    label1.Text = elapsedTime.TotalSeconds.ToString("0.0");
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Stop();

                    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:/Users/Lenovo/source/repos/Final3/Goal.wav");
                    player.Play();

                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        label1.Text = "GOAL!";
                        ballSpeedX = 0;
                        ballSpeedY = 0;
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                        label1.Text = string.Empty;
                        await Task.Delay(500);
                    }                   

                    StartNewGame();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                basketEntryTime = DateTime.MinValue;
                label1.Text = string.Empty;
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Image basketballImage = Image.FromFile(@root + "ball.png");
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(basketballImage, ballX, ballY, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

The other issue I have is that, even though I've placed the sound playback after the timer stops and before the loop, it runs after the loop executes and "goal" is typed.

Comment: some Arduino reset on new USB connection